# Gunicorn workers fails to start

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm creating a little application using Flask and I wanted to deploy the website online. I'm now facing an issue with gunicorn when I try to start. I use gunicorn with nginx. There is no problem with Nginx, i can access all my static files online but to start the website I need to run gunicorn.

Is use the following command to start gunicorn :

```
gunicorn -w 3 myapp:app
```

And I get this error that keeps looping

```
[2020-08-05 15:13:14 +0000] [2033] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4 
[2020-08-05 15:13:14 +0000] [2033] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2033)
[2020-08-05 15:13:14 +0000] [2033] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-08-05 15:13:14 +0000] [2035] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2035     
[2020-08-05 15:13:14 +0000] [2036] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2036 
[2020-08-05 15:13:14 +0000] [2037] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2037 
Usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] 
Try 'gunicorn --help' for help.
 
Error: no such option: -w
[2020-08-05 15:13:14 +0000] [2035] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2035)        
Usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] 
Try 'gunicorn --help' for help.
```

Here you can see the result of the command with the option --log-level debug :

```
[2020-08-06 06:02:29 +0000] [3943] [DEBUG] Current configuration: 
  config: None
  bind: ['127.0.0.1:8000']
  backlog: 2048
  workers: 3
  worker_class: sync
  threads: 1
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  timeout: 30
  graceful_timeout: 30 
  keepalive: 2
  limit_request_line: 4094
  limit_request_fields: 100
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  reload: False
  reload_engine: auto
  reload_extra_files: []
  spew: False
  check_config: False
  preload_app: False
  sendfile: None
  reuse_port: False
  chdir: /home/ubuntu/MyWebsite/server
  daemon: False
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  user: 1000
  group: 1000
  umask: 0
  initgroups: False
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  accesslog: None
  disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  errorlog: -
  loglevel: debug
  capture_output: False
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  logconfig_dict: {}
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  dogstatsd_tags:
  statsd_prefix:
  proc_name: None
  default_proc_name: app:app
  pythonpath: None
  paste: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f5c482e2160>
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f5c482e2280>
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f5c482e23a0>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f5c482e24c0>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f5c482e25e0>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f5c482e2700>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f5c482e2820>
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f5c482e2940>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f5c482e2a60>
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f5c482e2b80> 
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f5c482e2c10>
  child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7f5c482e2d30>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f5c482e2e50>
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f5c482e2f70>
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f5c482ef0d0>
  proxy_protocol: False
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  keyfile: None
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 2
  cert_reqs: 0
  ca_certs: None
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: None
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
  strip_header_spaces: False
[2020-08-06 06:02:29 +0000] [3943] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-08-06 06:02:29 +0000] [3943] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2020-08-06 06:02:29 +0000] [3943] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (3943)
[2020-08-06 06:02:29 +0000] [3943] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-08-06 06:02:29 +0000] [3945] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3945
[2020-08-06 06:02:29 +0000] [3946] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3946
[2020-08-06 06:02:29 +0000] [3947] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3947 
[2020-08-06 06:02:29 +0000] [3943] [DEBUG] 3 workers 
Usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] 
Try "gunicorn --help" for help.

Error: no such option: -w
[2020-08-06 06:02:29 +0000] [3945] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3945)
Usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] 
Try "gunicorn --help" for help.

Error: no such option: -w 
[2020-08-06 06:02:30 +0000] [3946] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3946)
[2020-08-06 06:02:30 +0000] [3948] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3948
```

Does someone know how to fix this problem or have an idea where the problem can come from ?

Thanks

Comment: There's no way to debug the problem without any error traces. Try to run wit the options `--log-level debug` and update the output to the question.

Comment: I've ran again the command with the option that you said, you can see the output in my post.